# How to search Windows Explorer for file names containing invalid characters?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, search, special-characters

I have downloaded over 10,000 files and need to move them to a different folder than my downloads folder. Unfortunately, these files have miscellaneous names, and some of them contain invalid characters (particularly a forward slash "/", such as when a file is named "filename 1/2").

These files are individually placed in folders, so I need to remove them by searching with "*", sorting by file type, and selecting the files not in folders. When clicking/dragging to a new folder, the entire window freezes and needs to be restarted. As a workaround, I was attempting to compress the files into a zipped folder to move more easily.

Unfortunately, the compression does not work with file names containing invalid characters. Attempting to search for a forward slash produces no results. **Escaping the forward slash with a ~="/" search also produces no results**, which is unfortunate since that is the only answer I've found via Google.

A manual search will take far too long. Attempting to compress gives a specific filename (in an error message) which I can then search for, but the compression attempt also takes a significant amount of time, so this process would be lengthy as well.

I'm willing to use any other workarounds for moving large quantities of files as well, but I think it would be productive to clean the file names to prevent similar issues in the future. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: If those files are already in a separate folder, just moving the folder to another location should be instantaneous. Have you tried using `mv ` from the commandline?

Comment: The problem with that is that I do not only need to move the files, I also need to restructure them since each single file is in its own separate folder. That was the purpose of the * search.

Comment: If you don't mind using Powershel, I'd start with building a list of file using `[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles(<yourdownloadfolder>,"*","AllDirectories")`. With that info at hand, it becomes easy(ier) to match each file to a specific pattern and use `move-item` to move it to where you want.